# copy python code of operation

Tags: python

In blender, you can hold your mousecursor over a button to see both what it does, as well as the python code that it would run.

[image]

This is an amazing feature. But it still requires me to remember the code before I can copy it into a text editor. Is there a way such that I can press a shortcut and copy the code that is shown on hover?

In the case of the above screenshot, I would like to copy `bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in the lastest version of Blender, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> while overing any *button* (of sorts) to get the Data Path; This, however, doesn't work with *Fields* (text or numeric), since it copies the value that is already in the field. To fix this there's a "workaround", press <kbd>RMB</kbd> (right click) and select `Copy Data Path`, this however only copies a relative data path;

Also, it wasn't working in 2.72 for me, but I updated to 2.72b and it did.